# Delphi: XOR, HEX, encryption

Tags: delphi, encryption, hex, xor

Is there a way to encrypt with XOR and represent in HEX (and the reverse). (I suppose not, couldn't find that).

Is there an alternative? I don't want to use Base64.

So I need to encrypt and represent the result in a readable form.

Comment: Base64 is the most common encoding for this type of thing. Plain XOR for encryption is not a good idea at all (not secure). Please state your problem more clearly - I have a hard time figuring what it is you're after.

Comment: calling xor encryption is a bit of a stretch. And what's wrong with base64? What format is your input?

Comment: Which kind of input data are you expecting? string? rawbytestring? memory pointer? On which version of Dephi?

Comment: Ok, I won't use XOR. And I'll use Base64 to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function applying a XOR to a string, then return the result as hexadecimal:

```
function XorToHex(const Source: string; Code: char): string;
const
  HexChars: array[0..15] of char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var i: Integer;
    c: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result,Length(Source)*(sizeof(char)*2));
  for i := 1 to Length(Source) do begin
    c := Ord(Source[i]) xor Ord(Code);
    {$IFDEF UNICODE}
    result[i*4-3] := HexChars[(c and 7) shr 4];
    result[i*4-2] := HexChars[(c and 7) and 15];
    c := c shr 8;
    result[i*4-1] := HexChars[c shr 4];
    result[i*4]   := HexChars[c and 15];
    {$ELSE}
    result[i*2-1] := HexChars[c shr 4];
    result[i*2]   := HexChars[c and 15];
    {$ENDIF}
  end;
end;
```

Such basic XOR is not strong at all. It's very easy to guess the key code, which is only one Char.

But this function will work with both Unicode and not Unicode strings.

Comment: I don't like the `*{$IFDEF UNICODE}4{$ELSE}2{$ENDIF}` part. The correct way would be: `*SizeOf(Char)*2`, IMO. That is also folded into a constant, but much better readable.

Comment: why not use built in conversion functions?

Comment: @Rudy You're right. I've corrected this. I wrote this function directly in SO.

Comment: @David I wrote the answer in SO, without any Delphi nor help at hand. A pure SysUtils function would make the trick also. This version is doing the xor and the hexa conversion at the same time - HEXA encoding is very easy to code directly - that was my point here. But since the OP question is vague, it was difficult to know how the input is formed. If it's a memory buffer or a RawByteString which is expected, it won't work with this code. I made some decisions, perhaps not outside OP expectation.

Answer (score 1):

all of you point out how weak is xor encryption, but you all only thought of using a single value to xor by. Instead you can easily xor a string with another string - a key. The longer the key, the stronger the actual encryption, and with key long enough it becomes really hard to break.

You can even xor-encrypt a memory stream, just as you can a string:

```
Procedure XorStream(const StreamToXor: TMemoryStream; const XorKey: string);
   var
     i,k : int64;
     PC  : PChar;
   begin
     if(StreamToXor=nil)then exit;
     if(StreamToXor.Size<1)then exit;
     if(XorKey='')then exit;
     PC := StreamToXor.Memory;
     k := 0;
     for i:=0 to StreamToXor.Size-1 do
         begin
           inc(k); if(k>Length(XorKey))then k := 1;
           PC[i] := char(byte(PC[i]) xor byte(XorKey[k]));
         end;
   end;
```

Answer (score 0):

XOR encryption is called a Stream Cypher, you can Google for different versions.

Converting a byte array to hex is just a matter of expressing each individual byte in base 16 with zero padding for bytes 0x00 to 0x0F.

What precisely is your problem with either of these?

Comment: Though plain XOR can be called a stream cipher, a stream cipher is a wider concept - it is a class of ciphers, not only XOR. For example popular RC4 algorithm is a stream cipher.

Comment: And RC4 is also an XOR cypher.  The RC4 engine generates a keystream which is XORed with the plaintext to produce the cyphertext.

Comment: I don't like the idea of calling stream ciphers as XOR ciphers. Using XOR is not compulsory for a stream cipher, it is just a most common form of a stream cipher. A stream cipher is about generating a pseudo-random bit stream, using XOR is a little implementation detail.

Comment: @Serg A Stream Cypher may not be an XOR cypher.  An XOR cypher is (almost) always a Stream Cypher.  OTP is the one exception I can think of, and that is impractical for all but a very small set of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Using **xor** binary function for encryption is poor man's encryption. It is simple and fast but easy to find the encoding mask key.

Here you have s simple test case:

```
program Projecth1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;

var
  Mask  :cardinal = $12345678;
  n     :cardinal;
begin
  n := $11223344;
  writeln('input: $' + IntToHex(n, 8));
  n := n xor Mask;
  writeln('encode: $' + IntToHex(n, 8));
  n := n xor Mask;
  writeln('decode: $' + IntToHex(n, 8));
  readln;
end.
```

This test case use only 32 bit mask and 32 bit input, so you can generate with another function longer mask array to increase secure level.